# How to deal with multiple large executables without having to upgrade a system?

Tags: storage

I often end up buying a new laptop every second year, which is a bit of a problem. I run multiple applications that take up a lot of storage. For work, it is software for scientific computing (MATLAB etc.), programming (e.g. Visual Studio, Android SDK, Java), and graphics (Adobe Indesign, Photoshop). For leisure I run multiple pieces of music software and games that usually take up a few gigabytes of storage each.

I do have an external hard drive (1 TB), but I would like to avoid depending on a modular system and I am not too sure if running executables from a disk other than C:\ produces expected behavior. I am guessing that this is a fairly common problem for power users and would like to ask what the most common solution is. The goal is to have a durable storage system.

I have considered buying a NAS for home use, but I am not sure this would be optimal. I am not looking for product recommendations, but more what technologies I should rely on to be able to run large executables from an expandable storage medium - the current laptop seems to need replacement.

Comment: If you want to preserve your environment exactly the same, then simply transferring (or cloning) your disk to the new laptop is your best option. I've done this several times now, my main Windows install has got to be about 9 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Tough scenario, because you're a demanding user.  What I mean by that is that you may want powerful computations for your work computing, fast responsiveness for your programming, and large data and responsiveness for gaming.  For many people, the fast responsiveness requirement is only at one location, but you have multiple.

As a clear answer to one question: having large executables on a network is just fine, as long as the network functions very well.  With a SAN environment, entire servers (computers which are virtual machines) might load all of their data, including the operating system, off of a network.  That does get done with high quality equipment, and works well.  Your concerns have been problems, historically, with older, low quality equipment where the networking has been less reliable.

These days, many people are using networks for streaming video, so networks are used for rather powerful things these days (even for many home users).

I'm a networking expert, and so I find the concept of a NAS to work very well.  If I want to change equipment, I can do so, and my new setup will typically be able to serve my needs with minimal changes.  In contrast, relying on things like modular/removable storage technologies may result in things being more challenging when you need to upgrade, because you may find that each change needs careful review to make sure it's not breaking at least one of the components of your overall solution.  The biggest concerns I have with networking are potential challenges if you're not familiar with networking (but that can be overcome through education), or tragic mistakes (like having it be in the background, so you stop thinking about it, and then you don't do something important like sufficiently take care of backups).  If you can address those, then networked storage may be a good option, as long as you can spend enough money to get equipment that provides enough quality and speed to make it work satisfactory.

Comment: I'd say outside of an actual *SAN*, NAS based application performance is going to be dreadfully slow. NAS devices aren't good for running things off (i.e. small random I/O).